# Can I use 2 v-fors inside the same drop down in Vuejs since I need to put labels between them?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is that possible to use v-for twice in the same dropdown? I need to add one static drop-down-item then do a v-for for the next ones after which I need to put another static b-dropdown-item and then again place dynamic ones after 2nd static one with v-for. I am going to use the following dropdown

```
<b-dropdown aria-role="list">
                <button class="button is-primary" slot="trigger" slot-scope="{ active }">
                    <span>Click me!</span>
                    <b-icon :icon="active ? 'menu-up' : 'menu-down'"></b-icon>
                </button>
    
                <b-dropdown-item aria-role="listitem">Action</b-dropdown-item>
                <b-dropdown-item aria-role="listitem">Another action</b-dropdown-item>
                <b-dropdown-item aria-role="listitem">Something else</b-dropdown-item>
            </b-dropdown>
```

Does it make sence and will it be possible to use such an approach for that scenario by adding 2 v-for after static middle options?

Comment: Why not just have one computed which generates this array for you? Fetch the data that's dynamic, insert the static entries in the positions you want, return the whole array?

Comment: why not giving a try? then if encounter any problem, you can still ask SO.

Comment: @con-- because css classes should be different for static and dynamic ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/adamzerner/pen/ExKdWMJ

Code:

```
<b-dropdown text="Dropdown Button">
  <b-dropdown-text>Letters</b-dropdown-text>
  <b-dropdown-item v-for="(letter, index) in letters" v-bind:key="index">
    {{ letter }}
  </b-dropdown-item>
  <b-dropdown-text>Numbers</b-dropdown-text>
  <b-dropdown-item v-for="(number, index) in numbers" v-bind:key="index">
    {{ number }}
  </b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
```